# How do you convert a Visual Studio project from using wide strings to ordinary strings

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, unicode

When I created my visual studio project it defaulted to forcing me to use wide strings for all the functions which take character strings. MessageBox() for example, takes a LPCWSTR rather than a const char*. While I understand that it's great for multi-lingual and portable applications, it is completely unnecessary for my simple little app. Quite frankly, it's more of a pain to constantly type TEXT() around all my strings.

Is there a compiler option, define or project setting which I can alter to fix this in my Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Properties then go to the following tree item:

> Configuration Properties -> General

**For Unicode select:**
 Use Unicode Character Strings

**For normal multi-byte select:**
Use Multi-Byte Character Set

When you put `TEXT()` or `_T()` around your strings, you are making it compatible with both of the character string options.  If you select `Use multi-byte character set` then you do not need anything around your strings.  If you select `Use unicode character set`, you need at least L in front of your strings.

By selecting `Use Unicode Character Strings` you are also by default using all of the Win32 API that end in W. Example: `MessageBox` maps to `MessageBoxW`.

When you select `Use multi-byte character set` you are also by default using all of the Win32 API that end in A.  Example: `MessageBox` maps to `MessageBoxA`.

Comment: Brian, how would you wrap a string with `L` if it came in the form of a command-line argument? Or would you only use `L` in front of hard-coded strings?

Comment: In VS2019, its now: Configuration Properties -> Advanced

Answer (score 2):

It is worth noting that you can explicitly declare wide character string literals of the form:

```
WCHAR *s = L"Hello Wide World.";
```

which requires fewer keystrokes than the macros TEXT() or _T(), but which will make a wide character string even if UNICODE is not defined.