# Comparing the difference of two C++ projects in VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, kinect, kinect-sdk

I wanted to create a new project of the same code as the kinect v2 standard bunch of code .
I made a new project in Visual Studio and add the copy of sample files of the other project in a new directory and added it to my project.
Also I added all the headers etc.
Then try to compile it and it make a lot of errors ! but it works fine in the sample project .
the CPP files and the headers are all the same.
So what can be wrong ?
I cahnged the Include directories in VC++ Directories to $(KINECTSDK20_DIR)\inc;$(IncludePath) and some errors get away but still there are errors!
These are the errors :

```
HCURSOR LoadCursorW(HINSTANCE,LPCWSTR)
HICON LoadIconW(HINSTANCE,LPCWSTR)
'=': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [25]' to 'LPCSTR'
'ATOM RegisterClassW(const WNDCLASSW *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'WNDCLASS *' to 'const WNDCLASSW *'
'HWND CreateDialogParamW(HINSTANCE,LPCWSTR,HWND,DLGPROC,LPARAM)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
'HRESULT StringCchPrintfA(STRSAFE_LPSTR,std::size_t,STRSAFE_LPCSTR,...)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'WCHAR [64]' to 'STRSAFE_LPSTR'
'BOOL SetDlgItemTextA(HWND,int,LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'WCHAR *' to 'LPCSTR'
```

sorry for my bad English grammer in advance!

Comment: Without those errors, it's impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Compare both .vcxproj (and .props if any) with a tool

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz How can I show you the whole of project?

Comment: You should start with pasting the actual errors you're getting into the question

Comment: @Ceros I copy and paste .vcxproj  file and correct the name still not working

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Here you go.I added the errors showing me.

Answer (score 0):

Your project most certainly has the wrong character set setting. You can find how to change it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727439/how-do-you-convert-a-visual-studio-project-from-using-wide-strings-to-ordinary-s).

A dead giveaway is lots of `cannot convert 'WCHAR *' to 'LPCSTR'` and similar. `WCHAR*` is `LPWSTR`. `LPWSTR` will convert to `LPCWSTR`<sup>1</sup>, but not to `LPCSTR` - this typically means that a wide-character literal is being passed to the function which resolves to a narrow-character version under the current project settings.

A carefully written project can compile under both settings, but most of the time only one of them is used and as such has to be picked correctly before building.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can pass non-const where a const is required, but you can't change the character type pointed to.